# C# how to remove the last comma in my loop using a condition

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 100;
        while (i >= 50)
        {
            Console.Write(i + ",");
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

I am just starting in c# for my class we need to add a condition to the loop so that the last comma does not print, I cannot figure it out. Please help!!!

Comment: Why are you not using a for loop? Using a while just makes it harder to read. | The check would be `if(i != 50)`. 50 will be the lowest i.

Comment: Well, IF i is on the last number, then write the number without the comma.

Comment: Split the Console.Write into 2

Comment: Is this the actual problem? Will you be printing from 100 always as an exercise or is `i` changing?

Comment: Console.Write(i + (i == 50 ? "" , ","));

Answer (score 4):

Is this a proper solution for you?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 100;
        int min = 50;
        while (i >= min)
        {
            if (i == min) Console.Write(i);
            else Console.Write(i + ",");
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some ways to do this are outlined below.

1) `while` loop - add an `if` statement inline:

```
int i = 100;
while (i >= 50)
{
    // if i is not equal to 50, print i with a comma,
    // else i without one
    Console.Write(i != 50 ? $"{i}," : $"{i}");

    i--;
}
```

2) `while` loop - don't use an `if` statement at all. Print `i` with a comma until `51`, then print `50` on it's own without a comma, outside of the loop:

```
int i = 100;
while (i >= 51)
{
    Console.Write($"{i},");

    i--;
}
Console.Write(i);
```

3) `for` loop - use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop:

```
for (var i = 100; i >= 50; i--)
{
    // if i is not equal to 50, print i with a comma, 
    // else i without one
    Console.Write(i != 50 ? $"{i}," : $"{i}");
}
```

4) `for` loop - don't use an `if` statement at all. Print `i` with a comma until `51`, then print `50` on it's own, outside of the loop:

```
for (var i = 100; i >= 51; i--)
{
    Console.Write($"{i},");
}
Console.Write($"{i}");
```

5) `string.Join` - let .NET do the comma work for you using `string.Join` and create the range using `Enumerable.Range`:

```
// this will print numbers from 50 to 100,
// Reverse() reverts the order (i.e. 100 to 50)
var csvString = string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(50, 51).Reverse());

Console.Write(csvString);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a good speedup by avoiding `if` control in the loop and writing to the console only at the end in one call:

```
int i = 100;
var values = new List<int>(51);
while (i >= 50)
    values.Add(i--);
var stringResult = string.Join(",", values);
Console.WriteLine(stringResult);
```

A functional alternative with linq:

```
var resultList = Enumerable.Range(50, 51).Reverse().ToList();
var resultString = string.Join(",", resultList);
Console.WriteLine(resultString);
```

Result:

> 100,99,98,97,96,95,94,93,92,91,90,89,88,87,86,85,84,83,82,81,80,79,78,77,76,75,74,73,72,71,70,69,68,67,66,65,64,63,62,61,60,59,58,57,56,55,54,53,52,51,50

Answer (score 1):

We call this a fencepost problem (something is different in the first or last iteration).
@yellowtail's answer works, but I find it cleaner to do one fence post outside the loop.

```
int i = 100;
Console.Write(i--);
while (i >= 50)
{
    Console.Write("," + i);
    i--;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Easy Solution to the problem:

```
        var result = string.Join(
            separator: ",",
            values: Enumerable.Range(50, 51).Reverse() // Create the needed array
        );
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```